# Toss bunched together chain in the air

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string

I have a metal chain that I fidget with sometimes. I notice that when I bunch it up in my hand and toss it in the air, the chain spreads out in its trajectory. When I was thinking about this, I thought if I was applying a uniform force to the chain as I tossed it in the air, the chain should stay together because each infinitesimal portion of the chain would have the same relative trajectory.

Does the chain spreading apart in the air imply that I'm not putting uniform force on the chain as I toss it? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: Short answer: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes. The reason it is very noticeable is because when some objects suddenly start moving faster, the space between them spread out. Think of some cars at a red light. When the light turns green, the first car goes, then the next, and so on. What was originally a close space becomes larger because the first car has a slight head start, and accelerates quickly.

If one chain link leaves your hand even a little bit before another, it will move a lot before any of the other chains catch up, since they haven't been thrown yet. Since they are connected, it will tug on the other links, spreading it out. If you try coiling the chain as flat as possible, and throw it very gently, the effect should be smaller than throwing it very hard.